# GWT Loading process

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm trying to trace how my GWT page loads

Tracing using Firebug after `mymodule/mymodule.nocache.js` has loaded a GET request is fired with request to cache.html file like this:

```
EF0C179631C4491034C07C47610CF86E.cache.html
```

I tried to hook on `XMLHttpRequest` via Javacript, I was able to intercept the loading of the module `nocache.js` and other resources on the page but not this `cache.html`

For example I was able to intercept the loading of a gif and extract its `src` attribute which is fired from a GWT generated `img` tag:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyModule/gxt/images/default/shared/blue-loading-3d.gif
```

So I was expecting that I can also  intercept the loading of that cache.html.

I am wondering how this html was called. Anyone knows? Is it fired from a anchor "a" tag? Or other?

Answer (score 1):

It's loaded in an iframe. Like that: `iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(base + initialHtml);`

Comment: More details here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideBootstrap; and note that it depends on the linker you use (but `*.cache.html` means the `std` linker –the default linker– is used).